# ckeditor Dropdown menu manager

Tags: ckeditor

I have a problem with the dropdown menu manager:

I would like to move the forms-buttons into the dropdown:

```
'DropdownMenuA': {
                    items: [{
                    label: 'form',
                    command: 'form',
                    order: 1
                 }
```

If I remove the original forms-group from the toolbar, the form-button in DropdownMenuA is also missing:

```
config.toolbar = [ { name: 'forms', 
                     items: [ 'Form' ] },
                   { name: 'DropdownMenuA', 
                     items: [ 'DropdownMenuA' ] } ...
```

-> button form is shown in dropdown

```
config.toolbar = [ { name: 'forms', 
                     items: [ 'noForm' ] } ,
                   { name: 'DropdownMenuA', 
                     items: [ 'DropdownMenuA' ] } ...
```

-> button form is NOT shown in dropdown

So, how can I have the form button in my dropdown without having it in the forms group in the toolbar?

best regards

Bernd

Answer (score 1):

sorry to tell you but it seems that some plugin commands, such as ' Bold,Italic,...,Forms' are not enabled without defining them into the toolbar first. I have neither found why this is happening,nor a workaround yet.